# Extract a company and company code from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this as below

```
var str = '101,1245###company1-|102,1221###company2-|102,1651###company3-|-';
```

Can we extract **company code** just before the comma(,) and **company name** just after ### and before - and store it in array so that i can pass this value in url for proper redirection

Comment: Yes, you probably can. What have you tried?

Comment: Is company code `101,1245` or only `1245`?

Comment: @M42 compnay code is before ,(comma) 101 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tmp=str.split('|');
var compnr_array=new Array();
var company_array=new Array();
var i=0;
for (i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
  var t=tmp[i].match(/(\d+),\d+###(.*)-/);
  if (t) if (t.length==3) {
    compnr_array[compnr_array.length]=t[1];
    company_array[company_array.length]=t[2];
  }
}
```

Ofcourse compnr_array is the array of company numbers, company_array is the array of company names. This assumes a company name doesn't contain a '-'